# Question about Image and Kernel in a combined Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to Linear Algebra, and was asked the following question:

> Let $S,T:V\to V$ be linear transformations, while V is a linear space.
>
> If $\mbox{im} ST={0}$ then $\mbox{im} T\subseteq \ker S$

I have tried to reason this through, but I am not sure whether my reasoning is correct:

$$\ker S: S\underline x=0$$

$$\mbox{im} T = \text{ column-space of }T$$

So if I multiply $S \times T$, with the result being $\{0\}$, that would seem to imply that indeed $T$ is a subset of $\ker S$, as it obeys $S\underline x=0$, with $T$ taking the place of $\underline x$.

Can anybody help out?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be the composition of linear maps $S$ and $T$ rather than mentioning it as multiplication? @dalta

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea - let's just be slightly more precise.

Suppose $y \in \textrm{Im}(T)$, so $y = T(x)$ for some $x \in V$. Then $S(y) = ST(x) = 0$ since $ST = 0$ and hence $y \in \textrm{Ker}(S)$. Therefore $\textrm{Im}(T) \subseteq \textrm{Ker}(S)$.